# NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem in Cordova / PhoneGap / Intel XDK

Tags: cordova, intel

I am looking for an equivalent to NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem (xCode / Swift), but for Cordova / PhoneGap / Intel XDK. Is Cordova able to interrogate the platform the App is running on in order to determine if a device is displaying data by default in imperial or metric? (That's basically what NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem will tell you).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not completely satisfactory, but in answer to my own question, I found:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization. Checking for "en-US" as the locale name can be used to set "imperial" vs. "metric" measurements. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413144/how-do-i-know-which-is-the-default-measure-system-imperial-or-metric-on-ios).