# How to find out the default units of measure system (imperial or metric) in Windows / .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, units-of-measurement

In Windows, ideally using the .NET framework, is there a way to determine the normal units of measure (e.g., SI/metric vs. Imperial/US/English)? If possible I assume this would be related to the PC's locale settings in some way.

---

Similar to:

- [How to know whether use metric or imperial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065049/how-to-know-whether-use-metric-or-imperial)
- [How do I know which is the default measure system (imperial or metric) on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413144/how-do-i-know-which-is-the-default-measure-system-imperial-or-metric-on-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`IsMetric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.ismetric?view=netframework-4.7.2) property on the `RegionInfo` class.

```
var us = new RegionInfo("US");
Console.WriteLine($"Is {us.Name} Metric: {us.IsMetric}");

var nl = new RegionInfo("NL");
Console.WriteLine($"Is {nl.Name} Metric: {nl.IsMetric}");
```

Prints:

```
Is US Metric: False
Is NL Metric: True
```